# Why on freebsd history i see command with *,never executed?

Tags: bash, command-history

On Freebsd 11,using bash

```
history |grep rm
  176  man lprm
  262  rm -fr /tmp/.[a-zA-Z]*
  481  sudo rm /b*core
  503* sudo rm -frv /
  509* sudo rm -frv /nfs
```

I see two commands with * (503,509) ,but I never execute them.
Why I see it?

Comment: could it be alias or .profile/.logout files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help history` (in bash):

> Display the history list with line numbers, **prefixing each modified
>       entry with a `*'**.  An argument of N lists only the last N entries.

Emphasis mine.

The lines with an `*` have been modified.